# I am getting the following error in my visual studio project "'IEntity': Cannot specify class dcpp(CS0450) at once"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a C# project that implements the N-layer architecture, my problem is mainly in the data access layer in the file "IEntityRepository.cs", this is the main structure of my project:

```
>Business   #is a project, class library
   >Abstract      #is a folder
       ICarService.cs
   >Concrete     #is a folder
       CarManager.cs
>ConsoleUI  #is a project, console application
        Program.cs
>DataAccess   #is a project, class library
   >Abstract    #is a folder
      ICarDal.cs
      IEntityRepository.cs
    >Concrete/InMemory #is a folder
       InMemoryCarDal.cs
>Entities    #is a project, class library
   >Abstract     #is a folder
       IEntity.cs
   >Concrete  #is a folder
       Car.cs
```

=> InMemoryCarDal.cs

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using DataAcces.Abstract;
using Entities.Concrete;

namespace DataAcces;

public class InMemoryCarDal : ICarDal
{
    List<Car> _cars;
    public InMemoryCarDal()
    {
        _cars = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car{Id=1,BrandId=1,ColorId=3, ModelYear=2021,DailyPrice=2500,Description="Volkswagen Passat"},
            new Car{Id=2,BrandId=1,ColorId=5, ModelYear=2020,DailyPrice=1300,Description="Opel Insignia"},
            new Car{Id=3,BrandId=2,ColorId=2, ModelYear=2019,DailyPrice=500,Description="Dacia Duster"},
            new Car{Id=4,BrandId=2,ColorId=6, ModelYear=2018,DailyPrice=760,Description="Ford Focus"},
            new Car{Id=5,BrandId=2,ColorId=7, ModelYear=2017,DailyPrice=350,Description="Hyundai i30"}
        };
    }

    public void Add(Car car)
    {
        _cars.Add(car);
    }

    public void Delete(Car car)
    {
        Car carsToDelete = _cars.SingleOrDefault(c => car.Id == c.Id);
        if (carsToDelete != null)
        {
            _cars.Remove(car);
        }
    }

    public List<Car> GetAll(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        if (filter == null)
        {
            return _cars;
        }

        return _cars.Where(filter.Compile()).ToList();
    }

    public List<Car> GetById(int brandId)
    {
        return _cars.Where(p => p.BrandId == brandId).ToList();
    }

    public Car GetById(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> filter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(Car car)
    {
        Car carsToUpdate = _cars.SingleOrDefault(c => car.Id == car.Id);
        if (carsToUpdate != null)
        {
            carsToUpdate.ModelYear = car.ModelYear;
            carsToUpdate.ColorId = car.ColorId;
            carsToUpdate.BrandId = car.BrandId;
            carsToUpdate.DailyPrice = car.DailyPrice;
            carsToUpdate.Description = car.Description;
        }
    }
}
```

=> IEntityRepository.cs

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Entities.Abstract;

namespace DataAcces.Abstract;

public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
    List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
    T GetById(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

=> ICarDal.cs

```
using Entities.Concrete;

namespace DataAcces.Abstract;

public interface ICarDal : IEntityRepository<Car>
{
}
```

Thank you very much in advance, I greatly appreciate the community
here is the complete code:
https://github.com/hdemiray/NLayeredConsoleApp/

Comment: It seems you have a problem in your `IEntity` interface but you didn't post that code, or what's in the `IEntity` is at odds with your `IEntityRepository` constraints. Based on the error you may have specified conflicting generic constraints. [CS0450](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0450)

Comment: Please provide a full [mre]. Or at least the full error.

Comment: Sorry, could I share the link with the code in Git Hub?